# Vectorised non zero groups in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Say you have 1d numpy array:

```py
[0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,4,5,0,0,0]
```

How would you create the following groups **without** using for loop?

```py
[1,2,3], [4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `np.split`:

```
a
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0])
### find nonzeros
z = a!=0
### find switching points
z[1:] ^= z[:-1]
### split at switching points and discard zeros
np.split(a, *np.where(z))[1::2]
# [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the indexes?